# Is it possible to intercept calls from one controller to another one in Nestjs?

Tags: nestjs

and I'm working in a backend application and I want to reuse some api writed before in other controller but its necesary that when I call a method for example from controller A to Controller B it must be intecepted by a Guard, middleware, etc. I'm using a global guard, that intercept any request call. And I  tried something like the example below but just intercept the first call triggered on controller A but when call to controller B it dosent trigger

```js
@Controller('controller-a')
export class ControllerA {
  @Get()
  methodA(){
    const respFromB = await ControllerB.prototype.methodB({ ..some data.. });
    enter code here
    return '...'
  }
}

@Controller('controller-b')
export class ControllerB {
  @Post()
  methodB(
   @Body() data: any
  ) {
    ... some other code...
    return 'books';
  }
}

// main.ts
const reflector = app.get(Reflector);
const authService = app.get(AuthService);
const prismaClient = app.get(PrismaClient);
app.useGlobalGuards(new MyGlobalGuard(reflector, authService, prismaClient));

// MyGlobalGuard.ts
@Injectable()
export class MyGlobalGuard implements CanActivate {
  public constructor(
    private readonly reflector: Reflector,
    private readonly authService: AuthService,
    private readonly prisma: PrismaClient,
  ) {}
  canActivate(
    context: ExecutionContext,
  ): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    ....
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you're the one calling from one controller to another, no it's not possible. You'd need to make an HTTP request from your server to your server to trigger the guards and interceptors again. It's Nest's internal route handler that's in charge of calling these enhancers, so you can't get to them from directly calling the class

Comment: Oki @Jay McDoniel thx!!!!! yep I'm starting to do that call as http